# After "ng build --prod" when trying to load the app it displays error in browser

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular-cli "beta.32".

When building using "ng build", the build succeeds and app can be accessed.
However, when build in production mode (using ng build --prod) it gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

[image: Below is the screenshot for reference]

When building using "ng build --prod --aot=false" and then serving the application everything works fine!

There seems to be an issue with AOT compilation when doing "ng build --prod" where by default

--aot=true

Comment: either your custom_functions.js or some vendor library is not AoT ready it seems...

Comment: those two files does not have an issue. It's the error below that. Below "ORIGINAL STACKTRACE" that is the actual issue.

Comment: "or some vendor library is not AoT ready it seems...". You gotta check which vendor library is the reason for this problem, some module you are including may not support AoT

Comment: This is not an issue related to vendor libraries. Just check and realised that it an issue with "@ngrx/store". The store is unable to get the "initial state" defined for functions when it is being initialized.

Now after doing "ng serve / build --prod" it gives me an error saying 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedId' of undefined".
This 'selectedId' is a property present in the initial state. But as the state itself is unable to get the initial state it gives me the above error